# Conflicting CocoaPod name from two sources

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When using two sources in our `Podfile` we are getting a collision with a CocoaPod that exists in the main spec repository and also in our private spec repository. Example `Podfile` assuming we have a private `AFNetworking` CocoaPod that we'd prefer to use:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/PersonalSpecs/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target :MyTarget do
    platform :ios, '8.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

When we run `pod install` with this `Podfile`, CocoaPods ends up choosing the spec that exists in the main spec repository instead of our own.

I don't want to specify the `git` path for the pod since that avoids our normal spec publishing process. I've also tried altering the order of the source definitions.

**Can we do anything to make CocoaPods use our private spec repository as the source for a given pod inclusion?**

Comment: Alter the order and try bumping the Pod version of your private repo. Source: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#source

Comment: I don't want to unnecessarily bump the version of my private `podspec`. Which order are you suggesting that I alter, @PrerakSola?

Comment: The order of your source.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried that without success.

Comment: Interesting, CocoaPods _should_ be using the order of `source`s to determine which pod it should use. Any chance you can triple check and raise an issue if it isn't?

Comment: Hey, @orta, I just circled back and this seems to still be an issue. Would you like me to file an issue in the CocoaPods repo?

Comment: Please, that'd be great

Answer (score 1):

CocoaPods checks sources [in alphabetic order](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/982) so an ugly way to work around the issue: rename your private source so it's higher alphabetically. For example: `https://github.com/AAAAPersonalSpecs/Specs.git`